LLM performance optimization
I am working on a project where I have to train and deploy a LLM on a large dataset (~100GB) with limited computational resources (16GB RAM, 4-core CPU) but having issues with memory overflow during training and slow inference times
details:
Number of Layers: 24
Attention Heads: 16
Hidden Size: 1024
Vocabulary Size: 50,000
Sequence Length: 512
Training Data: 100GB dataset (diverse text sources)
Training Objective: Masked Language Modeling (MLM)
Optimizer: AdamW with a learning rate of 1e-4
Batch Size: 32 (due to memory constraints)

I have tried

pruning the model and quantizing it but accuracy is taking a hit
mixed-precision training - not much chnaged

I saw a small improvement when I did batch processing
I am looking for techniques or libraries (specifically in model architecture and hyperparameters) that will help improve the performance without actually compromising the accuracy
